# Is there a way to remove all the contents in vBox in JavaFx?

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to do the a Javafx project. And I have some problem with it.
I have a list of text (labels) placed inside the vBox. Is there a way to remove all the text in the vBox? For example, when I click a button "Remove", everything inside the vBox will be disappeared. 
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Oh! I just figured it out.
I can use vBox.getChildren().clear();
It works!

Comment: It works. I wonder why `vBox.getChildren().removeAll()` doesn't.

Comment: removeAll() needs arguments.

Comment: what type of arguments?

Comment: @Panagiss Node type arguments.

Answer (score 3):

```
vBox.getChildren().removeAll(vBox.getChildren());
```

works too

Comment: i don't get it how and most important WHY that works